# How can I reach jquery.template contents from within ko.bindingHandler?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

There is an element with a [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com) binding (let it be "A"). The contents of this element is generated using knockout.js/jquery.tmpl templates. Is it possible to get this contents from within of the binding handler called on the element "A"?

Here is a simple example:

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-1.3.0beta.debug.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Some simple tmpls -->
        <script id="wrapperTmpl" type="text/html">
            <div data-bind="showBug:true">                
                <div data-bind="template: 'buggyTmpl'"></div>               
            </div>
        </script>

        <script id="buggyTmpl" type="text/html">
            <div class="buggy">I am out of reach.</div>
        </script>

        <!--
            Knockout won't handle{{tmpl}} calls which are not wrapped in knockout constructions.
        -->
        <div data-bind="template: 'wrapperTmpl'"></div>

        <script>
            <!-- Refers to elements from the child rendered using tmpl -->
            ko.bindingHandlers.showBug = {
                init: function (elem, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessors, model) {
                    var $buggyElem = $(".buggy", elem);
                    console.log("$(elem).html(): ", $(elem).html());        
                    console.log("$('.buggy'): ", $buggyElem);

                }
            };


            ko.applyBindings({});       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue is that the template gets rendered after your custom binding has executed.  You could deal with this by executing your init code in a setTimeout like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.showBug = {
    init: function (elem, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessors, model) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var $buggyElem = $(".buggy", elem);
            console.log("$(elem).html(): ", $(elem).html());        
            console.log("$('.buggy'): ", $buggyElem);           
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/njaeF/

Comment: Thank you, @RPNiemeyer. Timeout is a possible workaround, but is there some usual practice of dealing with example-like cases?

Comment: There isn't really another pattern to deal with this case other than using the `afterRender` callback.  The template needs to render before you can act on the elements.